# Call a python script that reads mbox file using batch script

Tags: python, batch-file

I have this code that takes as argument the path of `mbox` file and prints the last mbox file.

```
import mailbox
import sys
messages = mailbox.mbox(sys.argv[1])
print(messages[len(messages)-1])
```

I want to call this script using a `.bat` script in Windows, so I used the following code but it gives me this error

> KeyError : No message with key:-1

Here is the script that i used :

```
@echo off
set VAR_1= "C:\Users\hmk\Desktop\PFE 2019\ML\MachineLearningPhishing-master\MachineLearningPhishing-master\code\resources\email-enron.mbox"
python get_last_mail.py %1 VAR_1
pause
```

I used the same code with only static entry of the file path on jupyter notebook and it worked.

Comment: If you try running the script manually, setting using a string instead of `sys.argv[1]`, what happens?

Comment: First of all, reformat the code so that things are on proper lines. Secondly, either you are passing name of mbox file in argument to bat file and you don't need VAR_1, or you want to use VAR_1, in which case lose %1 and use %VAR_1%

Comment: it gives the same error using a static string

Comment: @Gnudiff ,now it tells me `IndexError: list index out of range`